# Prevent deleting related model instance - Loopback 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I've two models:

**User.json**

```
"relations": {
    "items": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "Item",
        "foreignKey": "userid"
    },}
```

**Item.json**

```
"relations": {
    "user": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "User",
        "foreignKey": "userid"
    },}
```

Loopback generates this endpoint:

DELETE `/User/{userid}/items/{itemid}`

I'd like to override default delete method so item won't be deleted only property `active` would be set to `false`.

> My question is: how can I override this default method or prevent
>   deleting record?

I've tried:

```
Item.once('attached',function(){
    Item.destroyById = function(filter,auth, cb){
        console.log('This is a overridden method')
    }
})
```

Which seems not be executed.

And:

```
Item.observe('before delete', function(ctx, next) {  
    var err = new Error("Not deleted");  
    next(err)
});
```

It works (item is not deleted) but error is thrown which I'd like to avoid. 
Maybe there's a way to pass some argument to `next()` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could implement the connector hook for that operation, where you can modify the db query on the fly.

```
var connector = Model.getDataSource().connector;
connector.observe('before execute', function(ctx, next) {
  // preview your query and modify it as desired
  console.log(ctx);
  // so when you call next it will be executed in a shape you've created
  next();
});
```

Here some more info about it: 
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connector-hooks.html